# WIFIonICE on DB trains (Deutsche Bahn) does never work (on Windows), no login page is displayed

Tags: wireless-networking

When I am on trains of DB (like ICEs), their Wi-Fi never works for me. I can connect, but there is no internet access. I cannot open the login page to accept the terms of the network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be different causes for this, apparently. But since it always happened to me, the problem seemed to be on my side.

It turns out that I manually set DNS servers in the Windows settings. This seems to cause the login page of the network to never be accessible.

Setting the DNS preferences back to default fixed the problem.

Posting this here as reference for others with the problem.

Also see https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/372503 and https://www.reddit.com/r/germany/comments/8fq5m5/comment/dy5mv2o.